# How to use Kafka connect to output to dynamic directory in GCS?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-storage, apache-kafka-connect

I am fetching JSON data from a Kafka topic. I need to dump this data onto GCS (Google Cloud Storage) into a directory, wherein the directory name will be fetched from the value of "ID" in the JSON data.

I googled and did not find any similar use case wherein Kafka Connect can be used to interpret the JSON data and create directories dynamically based on the value from the JSON data.
Can this be achieved using Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Kafka Connect GCS sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-gcs/index.html) which is provided by Confluent.

> The Google Cloud Storage (GCS) connector, currently available as a
>   sink, allows you to export data from Kafka topics to GCS objects in
>   various formats. In addition, for certain data layouts, GCS connector
>   exports data by guaranteeing exactly-once delivery semantics to
>   consumers of the GCS objects it produces.

Here's an example configuration for the connector:

```
name=gcs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=gcs_topic

gcs.bucket.name=#bucket-name
gcs.part.size=5242880
flush.size=3

gcs.credentials.path=#/path/to/credentials/keys.json

storage.class=io.confluent.connect.gcs.storage.GcsStorage
format.class=io.confluent.connect.gcs.format.avro.AvroFormat
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner

schema.compatibility=BACKWARD

confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1

# Uncomment and insert license for production use
# confluent.license=
```

You can find more details for installation and configuration in the link I've provided above.

Comment: This is answering basically nothing from the question itself...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible out-of-the-box using most connectors.  Instead, you can implement your own Kafka Connect sink task that processes Kafka records and then writes them to the correct GCS directories based on your JSON.

[Here's the method you'd override](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c74acb24eb1da5d16cc2721a63931cd87f79ec66/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/sink/SinkTask.java#L101) in the connector.

[Here's a link to the source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/S3SinkTask.java#L182) for the AWS S3 sink connector.